# redirection to login page ERROR localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php, html

Using PHP 7.1, MySQL, HTML5 Using localhost at present, I wanted to set-up a redirect from each webpage if the user is not logged in, to return to the login page login.php.

So I added the following include header.php to all of my PHP files

```
<!--    header.php
        on all webpages, checks if user logged in, redirects to login.php if NOT
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202153/how-to-redirect-users-to-login-page-if-they-havent-logged-in
-->
<?php
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION["username"])){ /* IF NO USERNAME REGISTERED TO THE SESSION VARIABLE */
    header("LOCATION:login.php"); /* REDIRECT USER TO LOGIN PAGE */
  }
?>
```

I am now getting the error

```
localhost redirected you too many times.
```

Having cleared all my cookies as recommended and rebooted my system, and I have removed the call to header.php from about 40 php files, it is still a problem.

I should say that it worked 100% until I edited my approximately 40th PHP file to add

```
<?php require('header.php'); ?>
```

Then the error was displayed in the chrome browser as follows.

```
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I can add the header.php to less files in the future i.e. by adding to a higher level php file.

1. how do I fix the error so I can continue to develop and
2. what change do I make to the code to prevent the error in the future.

I assume the system is now in an infinite loop, which needs to be cleared

I am desperate for a quick solution so any help would be much appreciated, I will continue looking for a solution in the meantime.

Many Thanks in advance, Colin

Comment: Is this an include file?

Comment: Try to add  `exit();` after redirection code.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have the same header on your login page !

Comment: Yes I should have said I did not add the header.php to the login page. I will try to add exit(); after the redirection, I am just using the <?php include directive to call all my php files from within another one, I assume this is ok

Comment: try to put ob_start() in top of header file and ob_flush() in end of the footer

Comment: I don't think is it a problem of `exit()` since the exit construct  is used for security reasons. the error message is coming from too many redirection meaning the header is redirecting to another header which is creating an infinite loop  !

Comment: which page are you trying to access while getting this error ? does this happen with all your pages ?

Comment: it appears to be happening with all PHP pages (40 odd) where I added the line <?php include('header.php') ?> at the top of the file, despite now having removed the line and saved the file to its original state. PHP files where I had not made this change work ok, this seems to be the pattern

Comment: Rahul, I have tried adding <?php ob_start(); ?> to top of login.php and <?php ob_flush();  ?> to end of login.php after call to footer.php but it still displays browser error

Answer (score 1):

The code after `header('Location: login.php')` is still being executed *unless* you know what you are doing *always* `exit()` after a `Location` header as this is much more secure.

Also, you can change the require to avoid a double include (that would cause this problem)

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
```

However this more of a patch than a code logic fix.

A better solution would be to do something like the following:

```
#header.php

if(!defined('TO_LOGIN')){
  define('TO_LOGIN', true);
  header("Location: login.php");
  exit();
} else {
  trigger_error('Another request to "login.php". debug: <pre>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(), true) . '</pre>');
}
```

Because if a client does not have cookies enabled, this would never cause the code to loop.

Comment: Thanks Xorifelse, I have now added the exit to prevent further occurrences, but do you know how I stop the existing code executing on my localhost, resulting in the error on my browser shown above, as I cannot continue until this is fixed. Cheers Colin

Comment: I've updated the code a bit, it will throw a debug if another include of `header.php` is made. This you can use to see which file caused the issue in the first place and fix it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, my file header.php (used to check if user logged in and call `login.php` if NOT logged in) was calling `login.php`

```
header.php
 called login.php
     called header-loginregister.php
         called header.php
```

so it was creating an infinite loop, I need to be careful where I place the include `header.php` call to avoid this mistake in the future.

So indirectly `login.php` was calling itself via `header-loginregister.php` and `header.php`

Thanks for all the comments on how to improve the code which I will implement.